# AWS Lambda task time out when adding newman

Tags: node.js, lambda, aws-lambda, newman, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to execute Newman using Lambda, but I keep getting timeout when adding newman in index.js:

```
const newman = require('newman');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
   console.log("aa = "); 
   callback(null, "some success message");
}
```

if I remove the first line - `const newman = require('newman');` the execution went ok.

My folder structure also seems correct:
index.zip
 - index.js
 - node_modules

Even when I add the timeout in Lambda, it eventually will timeout. Any idea on what went wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your lambda inside of a VPC?

Comment: no, I choose no VPC in Network dropdown inside my Lambda configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From personal experience, I believe you might not be allocating enough memory for your lambda function. I was having similar issues with newman in the aws lambda environment. Try bumping up the memory usage to see if that helps.